# how to searching number with text in perl?

Tags: xml, regex, perl

My XML data contain

```
<pii>S0002-9440(13)0072</pii><doi>10.1016/j.ajpath.2013.10.014</doi>
```

this text. I wrote perl script find this contents but my script cant find this S0002-9440(13)0072..

My scripts is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
print "start..";
@files = <*.xml>;
open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;
my $pii='S0002-9440(13)0072';
foreach $file (@files) {
    open(FILE, "$file");
    while(my $line= <FILE> ){
        if($line =~ /<ce:pii>$pii<\/ce:pii>/) {
            print $out("found");
        }
        else {
            print $out("not fond\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML you showed uses `<ppi>`, while you're searching for `<ce:pii>`.

Additionally, you're looking for a literal string within the tags, so you should escape it with [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or the parenthesis will be treated as regex special characters:

```
if ($line =~ m{\Q<pii>$pii</pii>}) {
```

Even better practice would be to use an actual XML Parser like [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML%3A%3ASimple&mode=all) or [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML%3A%3ATwig&mode=all).  Below is a demonstration of using both of these modules with some fake xml data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use XML::Simple;
use XML::Twig;

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'test.xml';
my $pii = 'S0002-9440(13)0072';

# Fake Data
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

# Setup Fake Data in a file
open my $outfh, '>', $file;
$outfh->print($data);
close $outfh;

# Regex
{
    if ($data =~ m{\Q<pii>$pii</pii>}) {
        print "regex - found\n";
    } else {
        print "regex - not found\n";
    }
}

# XML::Simple
{
    my $xml = XMLin($file);

    if ($xml->{pii} eq $pii) {
        print "XML::Simple - found\n";
    } else {
        print "XML::Simple - not found\n";
    }
}

# XML::Twig
{
    my $ppival = '';
    my $t = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => {
        'pii' => sub { $ppival = $_->text },
    })->parsefile( $file );

    if ($ppival eq $pii) {
        print "XML::Twig - found\n";
    } else {
        print "XML::Twig - not found\n";
    }

}

1;

__DATA__
<root>
<pii>S0002-9440(13)0072</pii><doi>10.1016/j.ajpath.2013.10.014</doi>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i agree with miller.

can we also do this way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

open(FILE,"<xml_file_path>") || warn "cant open the file file.xml";

my @array = <FILE>;

foreach my $arr (@array)
{

 if ($arr=~m/\<pii\>S0002\-9440\(13\)0072\<\/pii\>/g) # or if ($arr=~m/\<pii\>\w(.*)\<\/pii\>/g)     

        {
         print "pattern found\n";
        }

else    {

       print "pattern not found\n";
        }
}

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is an XML file, use a proper XML parser. For example, [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for //pii[.='S0002-9440(13)0072'] echo Found ;
```